# Install newer version of linux mint in place of older one and restore data from a backup primary partition

Tags: installation, backup, linux-mint, system-restore

Noob question but decided to ask just to make sure I do not mess anything up. I have a computer with windows 7 and linux mint 19.1 installed. Also I have a primary partition named "Backup" which contains a backup of my linux system made using the linux mint backup tool. I want to get rid of the older linux installation and install a newer one (20.1). I have flashed my usb with the newer version of linux mint but what makes me scared is the installation of the newer version. I tried already to install the newer version but I did not know which option to pick as when it came to the part to pick a partition where to install like [here](https://linuxhint.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/l21.png). Besides the options shown in that picture it also showed me an option to replace the older linux mint version with the newer one so i obviously clicked on that before I thought a bit more about it. Does that option also remove every other partition made by that os? After the installation I am planning on restoring my home dir from the backup I made. My home directory and root directory are on the same partition. How should i proceed to first install the newer os and then restore from backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good you asked, there is no need to install whole new system itself, just update to the newer version. [Here](https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade-to-mint-20.html) is a link that will help you.